# How to stop at 512 tokens when sending text to pipeline? HuggingFace and Transformers

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers

I want to test my model using Pipeline by Transformers. My model is a pretrained BERT, which works great if the given text is < 512 tokens. However, when sending the a larger text to the pipeline, it breaks, because it's too long. I tried to search, but couldn't figure out how to solve this issue.

This is my code:

```
def get_predicted_folder(text, model):
    pipe = pipeline("text-classification", model=model)
    if text:
        predicted_folder = pipe(text)
        label = predicted_folder[0]['label']
        score = predicted_folder[0]['score']
        return label, score
    else:
        err = "Error: The provided text is empty."
        return err, None

my_saved_model = "model/danish_bert_model" (it is saved locally)
label, score = get_predicted_folder(text, my_saved_model)
```

It gives me this error: `RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (1593) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1`

I tried to give `tokenizer=model` to the pipeline, and have this `tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_ckpt)` before calling the `get_predicted_folder` method, but it doesn't solve the issue.

The tokenizer inside the model is this:

```
def tokenize_dataset(tokenizer, examples):
    return tokenizer(examples['text'], truncation=True, max_length=512)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_ckpt)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda examples: tokenize_dataset(tokenizer, examples), batched=True)
```

Can someone please help me?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only add the tokenizer, maximum length and truncation to the pipe as well and it will work well.

```
 pipe = pipeline("text-classification", model=model, tokenizer=model_path, max_length=512, truncation=True)
```